# Consulta mysql com condição especial

Tags: mysql, join

Estou com dificuldade para montar uma consulta com duas tabelas.

No meu bd tenho duas tabelas chamadas disciplinas e boletim, em disciplinas tem os dados de cada disciplina e em boletim tem as chaves estrangeiras referenciando o aluno e a disciplina e um campo com a nota do aluno para aquela disciplina.

Quero montar uma consulta com a junção das duas tabelas que retorne todas as disciplinas e também as notas para cada uma, mas mesmo que não tenha nenhum registro na tabela boletim para a disciplina.

Tentei fazer como está abaixo, mas desse jeito só mostra as disciplinas que tenham um registro na tabela boletim, e quero que mesmo que não tenha o registro apareça as disciplinas com o atributo nota vazio.

```
SELECT d.id, d.nome, d.periodo, d.curso, d.ordem, b.nota d FROM disciplinas d LEFT JOIN boletim b ON (d.id = b.disciplina) WHERE (d.curso = :curso AND b.aluno = :aluno) ORDER BY d.ordem, d.id ASC
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: em `b.disciplina`, essa coluna guarda o que ? Uma string ou int ?

Comment: @LeandroLima é uma chave estrangeira referenciando a disciplina (INT)